# Negative decimal to fixed-point binary

Tags: twos-complement, fixed-point

IS -28.91 = 00100.0111 ??

28 -> 11100 then flip and add 1
-28 -> 00100

.91 -> 0111 with the accuracy of 4 decimals places

I have tried to check a lot of places to check my conversion if it is correct but I am failing at it. So I like to ask people here if I am correct.

Comment: This is a fixed-point format with 4 fraction bits?

Comment: yes for the fraction part.

Comment: I did the work on paper but I couldn't upload it here. I just want to know if I did the conversion correctly. I am seeing different solutions to similar negative numbers and it's making me think otherwise of my solution

Answer (score 1):

For addition / subtraction and other operations to work normally (by using binary addition on the whole bit-pattern), the whole thing (integer and fractional parts combined) as an integer has to be `x * 2^4`.

i.e. the actual value represented by `0b00100.0111` is `0b001000111` / 16.

That means you have to do 2's complement negation (binary subtraction from 0, or use the invert and add 1 identity) for the whole and fractional bits together.

Also, your value for `28` has its MSB set, so it's already negative, i.e. you've overflowed 5-bit signed 2's complement.  Presumably you actually have a wider integer part.

For 16-bit 12.4 fixed-point, `28.91`:

- `28.91 * 16 = 462.56`, which rounds up to 463.
- `+463` = `0b0000000111001111`
- `-463` = `0b1111111000110001`

As 12.4 fixed-point, this `0b111111100011.0001` bit-pattern represents `-463/16` = `-28.9375`, the nearest representable value to `-28.91`

Comment: Honestly man you confused me even more. I was not taught this way but I do understand what you did. But I'm not looking for the nearest representable value becasue i have to not only get the right binary but also show the precedures to convert it back to decimal and then present the floating point representation of -28.91 in a 32-bit computer

Comment: But I do appreciate the time you put in thank you

Comment: @Amir: oh, you said fixed point, not floating-point! I guessed that's what you were talking about based on having a `.0111` part for the fractional part converted separately. IEEE-754 binary32 floating point is *completely* different, with a mantissa and exponent that work differently.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format.  But unavoidably you will end up needing to round to the nearest representable value because `-28.91` is *not* exactly representable in 4-bit fixed point, or in binary floating point.  See https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html

Comment: @Amir: Also, normal IEEE binary floating point uses a sign/magnitude representation, so the difference between `-28.91` and `+28.91` is just flipping the sign bit.

Comment: So based on what I just went over the link you provided. 28.91 -> 11100.1110 assuming the MSB is set. Would this be right then? The reason I showed this type of binary representation is because this is how our professor showed us.

Comment: bro I just want to say thank you for helping out. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Bro I get it now. I got it

Comment: @Amir: you can mark the answer as "accepted" with the checkmark under the up/down vote arrow.